# Electric indent not indenting closing brace in perl-mode

Tags: indentation, perl

Starting with `emacs -Q`, I open a C file `a.c` and a Perl file `a.pl`.  I turn on `electric-pair-mode` and `electric-indent-mode` in each.

In `a.c`, I enter the following, where the `|` shows the cursor position:

```
int foo() {
    if (bar) {|}
}
```

I press Enter and get:

```
int foo() {
    if (bar) {
        |
    }
}
```

Well and good.  But in the Perl file, I start with:

```
sub foo {
    if (bar) {|}
}
```

Then I press Enter and get:

```
sub foo {
    if (bar) {
        |
}
}
```

No matter the level of indentation, the closing brace is placed at the beginning of the line it's on.

I could hack my way around this irritation, but is there a simple way to get the same indenting behavior in `perl-mode` that I see in `c-mode`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's just a bug in perl-mode.  The definition below should fix it:

```
(defun perl-electric-noindent-p (_char)
  (unless (or (bolp) (eolp)) 'no-indent))
```

Should be fixed in Emacs-26.

Comment: It's still broken in my 26.0.50, but your fix works, so thanks!

Comment: I just pushed the fix this morning, so unless you rebuild from a freshly updated `emacs-26` branch you won't have it.